# Audio recording and playback with libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I was wondering if anyone has any luck with audio recording and playback using libgdx. I'm currently using 0.9.8 and just messing around trying to make a simple voice chat app.

I create my audio device using

```
int samples = 44100;
int seconds = 5;
boolean isMono = true;
short[] data = new short[samples*seconds];

AudioRecorder recorder = Gdx.audio.newAudioRecorder(samples, isMono);
AudioDevice player = Gdx.audio.newAudioDevice(samples, isMono);
```

On a button press I kick of a new thread to record the data. (I know this is a messy to kick off a new thread, but i'm only trying to play with audio recording)

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Record: Start");
        recorder.read(data, 0, data.length);
        System.out.println("Record: End");
    }
}).start();
```

After the recording I play back the recorded data using

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Play : Start");
    player.writeSamples(data, samples, data.length);
    System.out.println("Play : End");
}
}).start();
```

On my laptop the recording and playback seems to work fine. I can record the data and then playback works great. 
The problem happens on Android. I've tried it on three devices (Samsung S3, Samsung Galaxy Mini and a Nexus 10). In all cases, the recording works perfectly, the issue occurs when I attempt the playback it just locks up in the player.writeSamples and nothing is played. I've left it 10 min and never prints "Record : End".

Has anyone ever got audio playback working? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of playing around, I found the issue.

Your line, here:

```
player.writeSamples(data, samples, data.length);
```

should instead be:

```
player.writeSamples(data, 0, data.length);
```

The second argument is the offset, not the sample rate.

So, to sum up, the following works on Android devices:

```
final int samples = 44100;
boolean isMono = true;
final short[] data = new short[samples * 5];

final AudioRecorder recorder = Gdx.audio.newAudioRecorder(samples, isMono);
final AudioDevice player = Gdx.audio.newAudioDevice(samples, isMono);

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Record: Start");
        recorder.read(data, 0, data.length);
        recorder.dispose();
        System.out.println("Record: End");
        System.out.println("Play : Start");
        player.writeSamples(data, 0, data.length);
        System.out.println("Play : End");
        player.dispose();
    }
}).start();
```

Comment: I haven't tested it yet but THANKS!!!! This has been bugging ;) the hell out of me.

Comment: I just tested it that was it... Thank you!! It funny that it seemed to work fine on the desktop version.